# Remove Woocommerce backends first text editor

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, text-editor

I hope that someone can help me. How do i remove the long Woocommerce text editor tab in Woocommerce backend? I only use the short description text editor.It's annoying that you see always the long description text editor.

[image: texteditor]

I hope that someone know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to your functions.php file

```
function rm_editor_woocommerce_products() {
  remove_post_type_support( 'product', 'editor' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rm_editor_woocommerce_products' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hide_toolbar_TinyMCE($in) {
    $in['toolbar1'] = '';
    $in['toolbar2'] = '';
    $in['toolbar'] = false;
    return $in;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'hide_toolbar_TinyMCE' );
```

Comment: This would be better if you included a short explanation why this code solves the OP's issue. For example, what do the various toolbars represent? If you have a link that users could refer to for more information, that would be welcome as well.